# Remove items from Mongo Aggregation if contained in an item array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using MongoDB Node.js

I have an products collection:

Example:

```json
{
    _id: '12',
    linkedProducts: ['1234']
}
```

If I had a product ID with an ID of `1234`, and it is linked to '12', what would be the best way to lookup through all products that has `1234` as a linked product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can first use the `$in` operator on the array field to find documents where the array contains the given id and then use `$pull` to remove this value from the array:

```
db.collection.update({
  linkedProducts: {
    $in: [
      "1234"
    ]
  }
},
{
  $pull: {
    linkedProducts: "1234"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here's a working example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nlBUWLdKERS